# Ayuda script listado discos

Tags: lista, redes

Buenos días a todos.
Mi objetivo es listar los discos de los diferentes equipos de una misma red de trabajo mensualmente para comprobar el tamaño usado de estas, y en caso de que este casi lleno envié una advertencia (En la misma carpeta donde se listan los discos, aunque con "ADVERTENCIA" escrito en él .

He visto que se podría con powershell pero no estoy familiarizado con él.

No es necesario que se haga con powershell, puede ser ejecutado por tareas programadas desde cada ordenador (aunque si hay alguna manera de hacerlo desde uno mismo mejor). Si encontráis alguna otra forma de hacerlo os lo agradecería.

PD: Todos son windows que pueden ser del xp al 8

Muchas gracias =)

Comment: Amigo, podrias colocar el codigo de lo que llevas hecho

Comment: Lo siento, solo se símbolo del sistema y no existe tal función

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale ya lo resolví con powershell usando el siguiente comando:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk |Where-Object { $_.DriveType -ge 3 }| Select DeviceID,VolumeName,@{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.size/1gb)}},@{Name="FreeSpace(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.freespace/1gb)}}
```

Para aquellos que tuvieron mi problema `$_.DriveType -ge 3` indica las unidades locales y de red. Según el numero que pongas obtendrás 2=externas 3=locales 4=red, por ello puse ge(mayor o igual).
Lo demás indica la letra que tu tengas puesto en el disco donde ejecutes el script, el nombre de la unidad(en el equipo destino),tamaño completo y espacio libre del disco